# gofmt extremely slow to complete

Tags: go

I'm on an iMac 27'' late 2013 model and I want to run the `gofmt` tool against [my package](https://github.com/sergiotapia/smitego).

I'm calling it like so:

```
iMacs-Image:sergiotapia ~/smitego $ gofmt
```

And it's frozen there forever, never completing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're calling it incorrectly. `gofmt` expects a source file on its standard input and outputs formatted code on standard output. Use `go fmt` (with a space) inside the directory of the package you want to format to format the code inside a package.

Comment: Are you sure? This command doesn't modify my code (git status after running) at all. The command I used was taken directly from their style guide: https://github.com/sergiotapia/go-style-guide

Comment: Did you run go fmt from the directory that contains your source files? go fmt prints the names of all source files that were altered. Did you try to intentionally change a source file in a way that go fmt would fix?

Comment: Yes, ran it from the right place. Can you give me an example of code that would be fixed by go fmt to test? Thanks!

Comment: `gofmt -h` gives you the full help. I think you are looking for `-w=false: write result to (source) file instead of stdout`

Comment: `gofmt -w myfile.go` will format and save your file. `gofmt -w` will format and save every file in the current directory and subdirectories, I think.

Comment: I just wanted to add, in a directory with multiple packages, you can run the command `go fmt ./...` to recursively fmt all go source files.

Comment: @Serg Write something that does a function call and don't put spaces after your commas.